# Java - HttpURLConnection - How to insert user data into Header Response

Tags: java, http, servlets, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I have a java servlet class that is performing a GET to a specific URL. I am also passing data as part of the GET.

What I need, is in my HTTP Server code that recieves this data, how do I insert user based response data into the Header back so my calling Java servlet class can read it.

I can read standard response things like .getResponseCode() etc, but I need to insert my own response into the header some how. How can this be done? and how can I read it?

This is my java servlet send class:

```
public void sendRequest(String data, String sendUrl) throws Throwable{

    String messageEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
    String message = URLDecoder.decode(messageEncoded);
    System.out.println("messageEncoded : " + messageEncoded);
    System.out.println("messageDecoded : " + message);

    try {                 
        URL url = new URL(sendUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();            
        connection.setDoOutput(true);            
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");            
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());           
        writer.write(message);    
        writer.close();   

        BufferedReader rd = null; 
        StringBuilder sb = null; 
        String line = null; 

        System.out.println(" *** headers ***"); 
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> headernew : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) { 
            System.out.println(headernew.getKey() + "=" + headernew.getValue()); 
        } 

        System.out.println(" \n\n*** Body ***"); 
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 
        sb = new StringBuilder(); 

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + '\n'); 
        } 

        System.out.println("body=" + sb.toString());     

        System.out.println("connection.getResponseCode() : " + connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("connection.getResponseMessage()" + connection.getResponseMessage());

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            // Ok
        } else {                
            // Server returned HTTP error code.            
        }   

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {            
        // ...
        System.out.println(this.getClass() + " : MalformedURLException Error occured due to: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        System.out.println(this.getClass() + " : IOException Error occured due to: " + e);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the header? in request at client or in response at server

Comment: Hi @RameshPVK I am wanting to put some application specific data, such as responseType, responseStatus, errorCode and error Description. This needs to be added in the response at server

Comment: That's not servlet code you've posted, it is client code. Your question remains obscure.

Comment: sorry, this is not my servlet code, but the class that the servlet passes onto do the processing